# Django ModelForm to update profile picture does not save the photo

Tags: python, django, upload, modelform, profile-picture

I want to enable my users to change their profile picture. When uploading a photo, I am redirected to the success page but the photo is not uploaded to the folder and the associated field is blank. Note that if a user already had a photo, it resets the field to blank so after submitting the form, the user has no photo anymore.

My guess is that the form.save(commit=False) does not upload the photo nor update the field as it should but I do not understand why !

Here is the model, view and form :

The Profil model:

```
class Profil(models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
photo_profil=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='img/profils', verbose_name="Photo de profil", help_text="La taille du fichier doit être inférieure à {0}Mo. Seules les extensions .png, .jpeg et .jpg sont acceptées.".format(str(int(MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE/1000000))))
cours_valides=models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255,validators=[int_list_validator])
niveau_valides=models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255,validators=[int_list_validator])

def __str__(self):
    return "Profil de {0}".format(self.user.username)
```

The ModelForm:

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=models.Profil
    fields=('photo_profil',)
def clean_photo(self):
    photo=self.cleaned_data.get('photo_profil')
    if photo.size>settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("Le fichier envoyé depasse la limite de %sMo.".format(str(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE/1000000))))
    return photo
```

And the view :

```
@login_required()
def change_photo(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=forms.PhotoForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            profil=form.save(commit=False)
            profil.user=request.user
            profil.save()
            return redirect('espace_personnel')
    else:
        form=forms.PhotoForm()
    return render(request,'utilisateurs/registration/change_photo.html',{'form':form})
```

Finally the template:

```
{% block item %}
    <h3> Modifier sa photo de profil </h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="{{user.profil.photo_profil_url}}" alt="{{user.username}}" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <h5>Photo actuelle</h5>
            <p class="text-justify"> Votre photo n'est visible pour les autres utilisateurs qu'à côté des commentaires que vous laissez sur le site.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.photo_profil}}
    </div>
    <p class="alert alert-info">{{form.photo_profil.help_text}}</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
{% endblock item %}
```

I have a read a few topics already but without success.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Matthieu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure that you have `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` specified in your `settings.py` file.

Also, add these lines in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Apart from that, in `html form`, add `enctype="multipart/form-data` in `<form>` tag, like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Make sure you have all these correct in your django app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a mistake in my template :)!! I had forgotten the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had forgotten the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"